# Toggle Feature - Version Control Workflow

Tags: github, jenkins, merge, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I was taking a look how Toggle Feature work. Actually, I am using a simple version control workflow. One `master` branch, that is always ready to be deployed in production and another branch called `develop`. New features branch are forked from `develop` and then merged back to `master`, when it is stable. So we merged back the `develop` branch to `master`. When we push `master` to repository it triggers a Jenkins Job, that runs tests and deploy to production.

So I would like to understand what is the rigth (or most common) version control workflow when dealing with feature toggles.

Do I am going to have just a master branch, and all develops works on it?

Or the common approach is to have all developers working on develop branch, and merged regularly to master branch?

Answer (score 0):

The one has nothing to do with the other. A feature toggle is just a fancy name for an option in your application; in your config file, you enter "COOL_FEATURE = off", and then you have all the time in the world to develop your feature (possibly in multiple branches; all merged into `master` and deployed to production over time). Only when the thing is really feature, you enable the feature ("COOL_FEATURE = on").

Comment: I know the technique. My question is about every developers team will work on the master branch. So every commit will put code direct in production? or is it better to have a develop branch and all dev work on it.?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want to achieve. The "official" gitflow workflow is documented at http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ , but I encourage you to also look at other workflows, first of all http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/ . And no, obviously you do not want every dev to commit everything straight into production.